# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser : force X86?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

This object always uses the default on the system, so on an x64 machine, it will use an x64 Internet Explorer object.
Is there any way I can force it to use the x86 IE? The web page element the browser accesses does not work on x64 and is out of my control.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the Forms Application to compile in x86 within the property pages of the Visual Studio project.
`Properties -> Build -> Platform Target`

Comment: Does this force the embedded browser object to use X86 IE too?

Comment: It does, WebBrowser uses Internet Explorer in-process.  64-bit and 32-bit components cannot be mixed inside a process.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your program in X86 mode.